# Solving a linear recurrence with a boundary condition.

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations, markov-chains

Let $N$ be a positive integer, $p\in(0,1)$ and consider the recurrence
$$
\tau_{k+1} = \frac1p\left(\tau_k - (1-p)\tau_0-1 \right),\ 0\leqslant k\leqslant N-1
$$
with the boundary condition $\tau_N=0$. I was able to show by induction that
$$
\tau_k = \tau_0 + \frac{1+(-1)^k\left(\frac 1p\right)^k}{1-p},
$$
but I'm not sure how to solve for $\tau_k$ explicitly (in particular, for $\tau_0$).

For context, I developed this recurrence in trying to determine the expected time until absorption in a Markov chain on $\{0,1,\ldots N\}$ with transition probabilities

\begin{align}
P_{i,i+1} &= p,\ 0\leqslant i\leqslant N-1\\
P_{i,0} &= 1-p,\ 0\leqslant i\leqslant N-1\\
P_{N,N} &= 1.
\end{align}
For a given value of $N$, this yields $N+1$ linear equations which can readily be solved for $\tau_0,\ldots,\tau_N$, but this does not work when $N$ is allowed to vary. (If there is a more efficient way of solving this problem, by all means enlighten me.)